# Normalizing in SQL

Tags: sql

This is a rather simple homework question, but I don't particularly understand the question.

Lets say that I have an object with 2 fields:

int time int speed

I want to create a table and data model that supports this object, and I need to make the tables scalable and normalized.

I don't understand what this means.

I'm guessing that I can make a table for this object, and to add another column, say ID, that makes each entry unique.

Would this be a solution? The thing is that this just object is so simple, that I'm sure how normalization comes into play.

Comment: Lacking more information, I think you've got it: add a primary key and you're off to the races.

Comment: Thanks. When I saw the 'phrase' scalable I wasn't sure what to make of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right when you said that adding an ID to make the entry unique.

[Normalization](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) comes into play when you added that column.